# Query from MySQL to Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, select, schema

I've created this query to find in `MySQL` all schema for my database.

```
SELECT 
T.TABLE_SCHEMA, 
T.TABLE_TYPE, 
T.TABLE_NAME, 
C.COLUMN_NAME, 
C.DATA_TYPE, 
C.COLUMN_DEFAULT, 
C.IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  T 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON  
(T.TABLE_SCHEMA =  C.TABLE_SCHEMA AND T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME)
WHERE (T.TABLE_NAME= ? OR ? IS NULL)
ORDER BY  T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_TYPE, T.TABLE_NAME,  C.COLUMN_NAME;
```

I want to create same code for `Oracle` now.

Comment: Does http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.4.2.1/ref/rrefsqlj35034.html help?

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to all!!!

I've found solution:

```
SELECT 
TABE.OWNER,
TABE.TABLE_NAME,
COLO.COLUMN_NAME,
COLO.DATA_TYPE,
COLO.DATA_DEFAULT,
COLO.NULLABLE
FROM ALL_TABLES TABE
INNER JOIN ALL_TAB_COLUMNS COLO ON 
(TABE.TABLE_NAME = COLO.TABLE_NAME AND TABE.OWNER = COLO.OWNER)
WHERE (TABE.TABLE_NAME= ? OR ? IS NULL)
ORDER BY TABE.OWNER, TABE.TABLE_NAME, COLO.COLUMN_NAME;
```

Share if you want. Stay tuned!